# Sencha Touch 1.1. I need to populate a Ext.List Object from an Array Javascript variable, instead of a Proxy

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am working in sencha touch 1.1, specifically, using Ext.List. But instead of using a proxy to populate the Ext.List object, I need to load the data right straight from an array javascript variable like

```
var = [["1","Ángel Quezada"],["2","Christian Herrera"],["3","Francisco Quispe"]]
```

I don't have any trouble populating the Ext.List in the proxy way, first I declare le model, then the proxy and finally the List. According the next lines.

```
    Ext.regModel('Cronograma', {
        idProperty: 'nrocuota', 
        fields: [{name:'nrocuota', type: 'string'}]
    });

    Ext.regStore('CronogramaStore', {
        model: 'Cronograma',
        proxy: {
            type :'ajax',
            url: '/mSAS/cotizacion.do?method=generarCronograma',
            reader: {type:'array'}
        }
    });

    this.grdCronograma = new Ext.List({
            id: 'notesList',
            store: 'CronogramaStore',
            emptyText: 'No existe resultado ',              
            itemTpl: '{nrocuota}',
            listeners: {'render':function(thisComponent){}}
      });
```

But right know I have another need. I need to populate the List from an Array Javascript Variable, not using the proxy, I mean

how can I use the

```
var varArray = [["1","Ángel Quezada"],["2","Christian Herrera"],["3","Francisco Quispe"]]
```

to populate the Ext.List, I guess there's a way using the Ext.data.Store and its load method. but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is dynamic way of doing it, without using static data.

```
Ext.regModel('Cronograma', {
    idProperty: 'nrocuota', 
    fields: [{name:'nrocuota', type: 'string'}]
});

Ext.regStore('CronogramaStore', {
    model: 'Cronograma'/*,
    data : [
        { nrocuota : 'Ángel Quezada' },
        { nrocuota : 'Christian Herrera' },
        { nrocuota : 'Francisco Quispe' }] */  // Does not take array [[],[],[]] that was specified in problem statement
});

this.grdCronograma = new Ext.List({
        id: 'notesList',
        store: 'CronogramaStore',
        emptyText: 'No existe resultado ',              
        itemTpl: '{nrocuota}',
        listeners: {'render':function(thisComponent){}}
  });
```

// Here is the dynamic method.

```
function addToList(data){
    var len = data.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var note = Ext.ModelMgr.create({
            nrocuota: data[i][1],    //grab only name from the array
        }, 'Cronograma');
        CronogramaStore.add(note);
        CronogramaStore.sync();
    }
}
```

//now just call the function

```
var data = [["1","Ángel Quezada"],["2","Christian Herrera"],["3","Francisco Quispe"]];
addToList(data);
```

Comment: iterating over data and creating records and adding it to store manually is not a good practice, you should use store.loadData(data) method, so the store will automatically do what you are doing here manually

Comment: Why is this not a good practice, how would you insert the data at some index using store.loaddata. Also, if you go to sencha-touch.js, store.loaddata does the same thing. why such "not a good practice" is used  by sencha framework itself.

Comment: because why you need to reinvent the wheel if the library is doing the same thing in some method then why not use it instead of creating our own logic, and for inserting data after store is populated we can use add or insert methods, but the user indicated that he already has the array data, so why code 10 lines when you can achieve same using just one function call, and does user asked about inserting data at some index?

Comment: User definitely does not ask insert at some index, by telling that I was answering your "bad practice comment", also creating model (being a primitive) will be more efficient than using loaddata. So the reason of not using loaddata is "efficiency". How about answering how using modelmgr is a bad practice?

Comment: let's just not go into deep discussion which deviates from user's answer, lets allow user to decide what to do :)

Comment: Its not just about questioner, its about answerer as well, so if it is a bad practice, I need to know how, so that I can improve my programming skills and answers.

Comment: This answer actually considers what should be the behaviour when loading data in store, many things listed here is not used by questioner, but you should code in a manner that will not create bugs in future if you try to add new functionalities

1) why re-invent the wheel, if library is providing a function for doing something then why we should copy library code to achieve the same thing, 2) if we are providing model class to store config then store will handle creation of models, why use ModelMgr? (yeah i know sencha touch internally doing it, but whats the point of exposing that logic here)

Comment: 3) loadData internally adds all models instances in to the store in a single operation so that will only fire 'datachanged' event once, so if user is listening for that particular event then he will properly get it, but your solution will add all models one by one which in turn will fire 'add' and 'datachanged' events for every model, which isn't good if user is listening to that event, because 'add' event should only be fired when we are adding extra models to already populated store

Comment: 4) loadData also internally applies sorting and filtering to the records if sontOnLoad and filterOnLoad is true, which will fail in your case 5) you are also calling 'sync' method after adding every record, i am not sure why you have used it here but from the documentation i can say that its used to synchronize contents between store and proxy, this is not needed when you do loadData.    please if you have any more queries then you can directly contact me, but i don't want to continue this discussion anymore here, because good coding practice has different meaning for everyone :)

Comment: sync and add are standard methods of Ext.Store object. It is first time I have ever heard that calling methods of a class is a "bad practice"! Sencha support team and developer team themselves include use of "modelmgr.create" in their solutions (see sencha discussion and support forums and search modelmgr). May be they are not aware that it is a "bad practice". I am speechless.

Comment: you are not getting my point, i am not saying that using add and sync is bad practice but using add and sync instead of loadData is bad practice, and if you are still not convinced then simply i don't care :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    Ext.regModel('Cronograma', {
        idProperty: 'nrocuota', 
        fields: [{name:'nrocuota', type: 'string'}]
    });

    Ext.regStore('CronogramaStore', {
        model: 'Cronograma',
        data : [
            { nrocuota : 'Ángel Quezada' },
            { nrocuota : 'Christian Herrera' },
            { nrocuota : 'Francisco Quispe' }
        ]
    });

    this.grdCronograma = new Ext.List({
            id: 'notesList',
            store: 'CronogramaStore',
            emptyText: 'No existe resultado ',              
            itemTpl: '{nrocuota}',
            listeners: {'render':function(thisComponent){}}
      });
```

**update to use arrays instead of json object:**

```
    Ext.regModel('Cronograma', {
        idProperty: 'id', 
        fields: [ 'id', 'nrocuota' ]
    });

    var data = [["1","Ángel Quezada"],["2","Christian Herrera"],["3","Francisco Quispe"]];
    Ext.regStore('CronogramaStore', {
        model: 'Cronograma',
        data : data
    });

    this.grdCronograma = new Ext.List({
            id: 'notesList',
            store: 'CronogramaStore',
            emptyText: 'No existe resultado ',              
            itemTpl: '{nrocuota}',
            listeners: {'render':function(thisComponent){}}
      });
```

or already indicated if you don't have data available at time of creation of store then use `store.loadData(data);` function

i haven't tested this code myself so if it's not working then please tell me

Comment: that is static method, question strictly asks for use of an array.

Comment: he doesn't specified the data is available at the time of creation, if it is available then in my method he just needs to pass the array in the data config, he never said that he wants to create an empty store and then populate items after that :)

Comment: "I need to load the data right straight from an array javascript variable like var = [["1","Ángel Quezada"],["2","Christian Herrera"],["3","Francisco Quispe"]]" this is problem statement, I did not see data to be loaded from an array. Please see http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/103502-require-a-reason-for-downvote The answer downvoted under answer does not address question. i would be happy if your solution worked for array [[],[],[]] and not [{},{},{}].